# How to pass arguments to function (FastAPI endpoint) loaded from JSON?

Tags: python, json, arguments, fastapi

I have a FastAPI endpoint which takes up to 70 parameters and they are often added or removed.
I have also list of arguments sent to this API stored in `JSON` format (extracted using `json.dumps(locals())`), so I can easily reproduce the API call in the future.

I would like to call EP `/another-endpoint` which is gonna load arguments from `JSON` and call another EP `/my-endpoint`, how should I do it?

My code so far

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import asyncio

app = FastAPI()
app.mount("/", app)

@app.get('/my-endpoint')
def my_endpoint(
   arg1: int,
   arg2: str,
   ...
   arg70: str
):
  print("Doing some action with those 70 arguments...")
  ...
  return "Some fake response"

# Example arguments in JSON format
arguments_json = {
"arg1": 12,
"arg2": "extract",
....
}

@app.get('/another-endpoint')
async def another_endpoint():
  # I have tried using asyncio since I am calling another async function
  # but this does not work obviously
  response = asyncio.run(my_endpoint(arguments_json))
```

It does not work, obviously.

Comment: When re-using functionality across endpoints its usually a good idea to refactor it into a common function instead, so that you don't have the route wrapper around whatever you're calling. You may also use a Pydantic model to describe the expected parameters instead, which would allow you to serialize/hydrate the model using standard functionality (and add default values if a field isn't present, use aliases, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, I will think about your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert the JSON format arguments into a dictionary, then pass the dictionary as *kwargs* to the my_endpoint function. Here's an example implementation:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import asyncio

app = FastAPI()
app.mount("/", app)

@app.get('/my-endpoint')
def my_endpoint(
   arg1: int,
   arg2: str,
   ...
   arg70: str
):
  print("Doing some action with those 70 arguments...")
  ...
  return "Some fake response"

# Example arguments in JSON format
arguments_json = {
"arg1": 12,
"arg2": "extract",
....
}

@app.get('/another-endpoint')
async def another_endpoint():
  # Convert the JSON format arguments into a dictionary
  arguments_dict = json.loads(arguments_json)

  # Pass the dictionary as **kwargs to the my_endpoint function
  response = await my_endpoint(**arguments_dict)

  return response
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my idea (I have removed it from the question), since I though this is applicable to arguments on the function definition and not when it's called. I will give it a try.